# many DataContext singletons to perform LINQ within a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

For a class that I have, I am noticing I basically have to use the following scenario for each function within a class. Is this inefficient? Is there a better to utilize the DataContext object?

```
using (var context = new SomeDataContext(getConnectionString))
{
   //linq query here
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Dan: the correct link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx. Please don't post links to documentation on old versions of .NET.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for pointing that out.  I was careless.  It was not intentional.  Thanks for providing the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is designed to be used the way you mentioned.  You should create a new context each and every time you do something on the database.  As @Dan points out, creating a Context is extremely fast and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

That's a correct and proper way to do it because it guarantees that you are disposing of the connection by putting it in a `using` clause. Instantiating a DBContext is not prohibitively expensive either.

With that said, you are creating one DBContext every time you query your database and disposing of it immediately, so you are not taking advantage of Caching and other niceties offered by the DbContext class.

One "cheap and dirty" way to create only one DBContext per request would be to instantiate one on `Application_BeginRequest` and store it in the `HttpContext.Items` collection (basically in a temp Cache) and disposing of it on `Application_EndRequest`. Each class in your project would then get the current `DBContext` from the `HttpContext.Items` cache and use it. The connection will be properly disposed since `Application_EndRequest` always fires regardless of errors.

A better alternative is to use a Dependency Injection framework (Structure Map, Ninject, etc.) You can google for tutorials on how to do this. SO has several questions that would help you if you are interested in implementing it.

Personal note: Don't worry about any of that stuff unless you noticee that your app is performing too slow to be acceptable. Your current approach is fine.